# PhoneGap - Sending JSON encoding data error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I am using Phonegap to connect to a server to authenticate a user. The server expects the data to be Json encoded, and I will get the response back from the server.

```
var serviceURL = "http://appdev/PEPS-CS-Services/";
```

The serviceURL (APPDEV) is hosted on our network within the office.

```
var loginData = {
    'strUniqueID' : '123',
    'UserName' : 'User123',
    'Password' : 'Password123'
};
```

I have checked the login credentials and they are fine. When I try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL + "services/AuthenticationServices/authenticateUser",
    data: loginData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

I get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in my console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://appdev/PEPS-CS-Services/services/AuthenticationServices/authenticateUser. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I had a look around, and I was suggested to use `Jsonp` as the dataType in the ajax request, which does give me back the response I was looking for. However, it isn't alerted out as it should be, the console shows the url with the parameters used in the `loginData` variable, as below

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/xml:
http://appdev/PEPS-CS-Services/services/AuthenticationServices/authenticateUser?callback=jQuery164017807046906091273_1396515434941&strUniqueID=123&UserName=Mark&Password=Password1&_=1396515434963"
```

When I open the link in a browser i get the correct response, as below

```
<ns:authenticateUserResponse xmlns:ns="http://services">
    <ns:return>SESSION ID HERE</ns:return>
</ns:authenticateUserResponse>
```

However, I also get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error below it.

I have tried to change to `data: loginData` to `data: {'data':$.toJSON(loginData)},` but still the same error.

My questions are the following:

Am I sending the data over correctly? Why does the `jQuery164017807046906091273_1396515434941` get added to the URL before the parameters?

And why am I getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError` too?

Is this because the server is sending back the incorrect format of the data? It is currently sending back XML

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a familiar cross context issue, you are not allowed to request resource from another domain with simple ajax call and expect a result.

Instead, use a jsonp call and regiter a callback function to call when return result:

```
var success = function(data){
    /* parse JSON */
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    /* show json parsed data */
    alert(data);
};

$.ajax({
  url: serviceURL + "services/AuthenticationServices/authenticateUser",
  dataType: 'jsonp',  //use jsonp data type in order to perform cross domain ajax
  crossDomain: true,
  data: loginData,
  success: success,
  error: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Feel generous and accept the answer if it helped your case :)

Comment: Sorry this answer did not help me. I had to enable CORS on the service I was calling in order for it to work.